# "%fieldName is a required field.", in Magento2 REST API Call for GET Method Type

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Calling this `http://localhost/XXX/rest/V1/XXX/uid/2`

and My Model Code is

```
/**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $uid User Id.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */

    public function test($uid)
    {
return $uid;
}
```

and My Interface like

```
/**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $uid.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function test($uid);
```

In webApi.xml

```
 <route url="/V1/XXX/uid/:id" method="GET">
            <service class="XXX\XXX\Api\XApiInterface" method="XXX"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="anonymous"/>
            </resources>
        </route>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to changes parameter  `url="/V1/XXX/uid/:id"` to `url="/V1/XXX/uid/:uid"` as, your parameters name is `uid` at `test($uid)`